# why procedural generated mesh vertices are not connected?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, procedural-generation

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 public class MeshDeformer : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public MeshFilter meshFilter;
     private Mesh mesh;
     public GameObject nearest, contactPoint;
     MeshCollider meshCollider;


     void Start()
     {
         meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
         mesh = meshFilter.mesh;

         meshCollider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();

     }



     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
     {

         deformMesh(col);

     }
     void deformMesh(Collision collision)
     {
         bool[] isProcessed = new bool[mesh.vertexCount];
         Vector3[] tempVerticies = new Vector3[mesh.vertexCount];
         tempVerticies = mesh.vertices;
         ContactPoint[] contacts = collision.contacts;

         string collidingVertexes = "";

         foreach (ContactPoint c in contacts)
         {

             Vector3 localpoint = contactPoint.transform.InverseTransformPoint(c.point);


             int nearestVertexId = getNearestVertexId(localpoint);

             if (!isProcessed[nearestVertexId])
             {
                 isProcessed[nearestVertexId] = true;

                 collidingVertexes += nearestVertexId + ";";

                 tempVerticies[nearestVertexId] += contactPoint.transform.InverseTransformDirection(collision.relativeVelocity.normalized)/50;



             }
         }

         Debug.Log("Colliding vertexId: "+ collidingVertexes);
         mesh.vertices = tempVerticies;
         mesh.RecalculateNormals();
         mesh.RecalculateBounds();
         meshFilter.sharedMesh = mesh;
         meshCollider.sharedMesh = null;
         meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;
     }

     int getNearestVertexId(Vector3 point)
     {

         float min = Mathf.Infinity;

         int minId = -1;

         for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertexCount; i++)
         {
             float dist = (point - mesh.vertices[i]).magnitude;

             if (dist < min)
             {
                 min = dist;
                 minId = i;
             }

         }

         return minId;
     }


 }
```

[image]

What's wrong? I want all verticies connected.

I didn't notice any changes after

```
mesh.RecalculateNormals();
mesh.RecalculateBounds();
```

It looks like triangle map is going wrong?
I tryied to update triangle map in the end of function, but had no effect.
I think I don't understand some base principles of mesh edditing and make this mistake

Comment: _I didn't notice any changes_ Check if `RecalculateNormals` and `RecalculateBounds` are void or do they return anything? maybe you should do `mesh = mesh.RecalculateNormals();`

Comment: theese are void functions.

Comment: or simply `mesh.RecalculateNormals();`?